# trouble with POST method to send json data to backend

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post

I'm writing a frontend for some form and I'm trying to send JSON data to the backend, but here is some trouble.

Also, we have a backend on java and there is no allusion that we are getting something

```
script.js
const signUpBtnForm = document.querySelector('.form__btn_signup')
signUpBtnForm.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    let json = JSON.stringify({
        name: document.reg.name,
        phone: document.reg.phone,
        password: document.reg.password
    });

    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/users");
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    xhr.send(json);

    xhr.onload = () => alert(xhr.response);
})

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Форма авторизации</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <article class="container">
            <form action="#" name="reg" class="form form_signup" method="post">
                <h3 class="form__title"> Регистрация </h3>
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form__input" placeholder="ФИО">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" class="form__input" placeholder="Телефон">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form__input" id="password_registration" placeholder="Пароль">
                </p>
                <p class="password-length">Пароль слишком короткий</p>
                <p class="password-includes">В пароли есть недопустимые символы: .@$!%*#?&><)(^-_< /p>
                <p>
                    <input type="password" class="form__input" id="second_password_registration"
                                placeholder="Подтвердите пороль">
                </p>
                <p class="check-similar">Пароли не совпадают</p>
                <p>
                    <button class="form__btn form__btn_signup">Зарегистрироваться</button>
                </p>
            </form>
    </article>
    
</body>

</html>
```

I think that the trouble is in the script, not in the connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***.addEventListener()*** is causing **undefined** error, moving the conde inside condition removes the error for me,

```
const signUpBtnForm = document.querySelector('.form__btn_signup')
if(signUpBtnForm){
    signUpBtnForm.addEventListener('click', function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    let json = JSON.stringify({
        name: document.reg.name,
        phone: document.reg.phone,
        password: document.reg.password
    });

    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/users");
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    xhr.send(json);

    xhr.onload = () => alert(xhr.response);
    return false;
})
}
```

Also, your page is navigating upon clicking the **submit** button, you need to use

```
event.preventDefault()
```

as well. And move your **script.js** to the bottom just above closing **/html** tag. Form submission works for me.